# C : Making sure the element you return from an array is correct

Tags: c, arrays

Say we have this piece of `C` code:

```
int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

printf("%d", *(x + 1)); //prints 2
printf("%d", *(x + 500)); //prints 7209065 (...?)
```

As you can see from the second call, it still returns something...but it's garbage.

So I ask, how do you handle such a case in C?  ie, how do you know if the returned element is really an element that exists in the array or just garbage ?

Comment: From this and other questions you have posted here, I REALLY think you would be happier using C++ rather than C

Comment: hehe, well I am learning C for the fun of it (and to start dabbling with electronics and micro controller programing hopefully someday)...ie, what I mean is, it's not for work or anything.  So, my plan is to first try to get the hang of C as much as possible, and then move on to C++

Comment: @Dreas - that doesn't sound unreasonable, to understand what's really going on (so long as you realise there's some pain involved :-)

Comment: If you want to learn C for embedded stuff, fair enough. But it's not necessary to learn C before C++, if C++ is your final goal.

Comment: well, it's not really a "final goal" per ce...in the sense that I want to be able to know the differences between C and C++.  That's the main reason I started with C first.

Comment: C != C++.  As Neil said, there is no reason to learn one before the other, they are two different languages with different API's, styles, and methodologies.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-vs-c++.html

Comment: @Brian Agnew: ah yes...infact you can already see a bit of my pain from these questions I've been asking here lately heh.

Comment: @Ed Swangren: "C != C++" <= the more reason for me to learn both seperately

Comment: Exactly, but you say you want to learn C first and then move on to C++.  The only reason to do that is if you need to know both languages.  You would probably be fine just going straight to C++

Comment: Although, I don't mean to get on someone's case for trying to learn more than they absolutely have to :-)

Comment: Come to think of it though, coming from a high-level programming background including C# and Java, I wanted something a bit more radically different, hence why I picked C over C++.  And hard as it was to get my head around some stuff, it was still fun nonetheless.  That was like four years ago though, so I might be wrong :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add another variable that holds the length of the array, and whenever you want to access the array make sure you are within the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Simply speaking you can't.  This is just simply a feature / bug / design of the C and C++ language.

Answer (score 2):

Array boundaries are not checked at runtime.  They are simply chunks of memory with an indication of the type held within.  This is a language feature and it decreases the total overhead of your code.  Like it or not, it is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone has noted, you can't do this due to the nature of C. However, there are tools available that you can use to instrument your code, and perform further checks on memory accessing (for use during the development cycle). [Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) is one such tool, and one I found invaluable for identifying such issues.

Comment: Aside from dynamic tools like Purify, there are also static code analysis tools http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis like Splint.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is why the "smarter" data types were created - things like C++'s STL arrays, which can throw exceptions for index-out-of-bounds errors.

Comment: Note though, STL vectors won't check anything by default (operator[]), unless you are accessing them through `at()` method.

Answer (score 1):

C does not check array boundaries. The onus is on you to check that access is within bounds by comparing against array length ( `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` ).

Answer (score 0):

Practically, either a 0-terminated array, where you have 0 at the end of an array and restrict yourself to traversing it sequentially, or you pass a variable containing the array's length around with the array and check that before all your array accesses.

An array in C does not know, intrinsically, how long it is, and so you cannot get any behavior that relies on that for free.

Comment: "restrict yourself to traversing it sequentially" - but that would mean losing O(1) for access, no ?

Comment: It certainly would, in cases where you need checked O(1) access.

Answer (score 0):

This is also why in most of the (more reliable) C libs that use arrays, you see the size of the array passed as a parameter, e.g., fread() fwrite()

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on JaredPar's and Ed's answers:

C arrays are a block of contiguous memory.  When you say int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  C allocates enough memory for 5 integers.   You're asking for the 500th element, so what you're getting is memory that hasn't been properly allocated to X.   It's garbage, and it may change each time you run it.

I agree with Rob.  Add a variable with the number of elements in X and just do a for loop through each.

If you want arrays that change length at runtime there are better ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are "lucky" enough, or your index deviation is large enough, then 
you won't get "garbage" - you will get a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). but that's actually a good thing, because it helps you to realize that you are doing something wrong. some tools tell you the exact line in which this has occurred.

Sometimes this depends on the input of the program, meaning a segfault occurs only when some input was inserted (for example if your '500' value was received as an input from the user). (those are slightly more annoying to find and handle)

The most problematic cases, are the ones in which you do get "garbage" and "have no way on knowing it".

On those cases there is really no replacement for writing good code in the first place.
But as others suggested, [Dynamic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_code_analysis) and [Static analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) tools may help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In large part it's a mistake to think of C as having an "array" type.  The syntax you're using is sugar around pointers.  **x[y]** is really syntactic sugar for ***x + sizeof(something) * y** (where the "something" is more complicated than I want to get into; in this case something is **int**).

Remember that C is a mid-level language ... a sort of "portable assembly" and you won't bring unwarranted expectations to the table.